# Appending data to JSON file C# winforms

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I would like to append data into a JSON file and I don't know how to do this. I tried using Newtonsoft but I cannot make it work.

JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Banana",
    "Calories": "88,7",
    "Country": "Africa",
    "Longtitude": 12123,
    "Latitude": 12345
  },
  {
    "Name": "Pineapple",
    "Calories": "88,7",
    "Country": "South America",
    "Longtitude": 12123,
    "Latitude": 12345
  }
]
```

My class:

```
public class Smoothie
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Calories { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public double Longtitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
    }
```

And how I try to add it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Smoothie smoothie = new Smoothie();
            smoothie.Name = inpName.Text;
            smoothie.Calories = inpCalories.Text;
            smoothie.Country = inpCountry.Text;
            smoothie.Longtitude = double.Parse(inpLong.Text);
            smoothie.Latitude = double.Parse(inpLat.Text);

            using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText("info.json"))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(file, smoothie);
            }
}
```

How do I properly add data to the JSON file? I also get an error saying `info.json` is already being used by another process.

Comment: It could be that you have the file open already somewhere else in your program, so check that you haven't got a hold on it already (or you open it with file sharing flags set), or it could open in another program which has got a hold on it. You could read the current file data into an object, do comparisons and update/add new items to the object, then serialise the object into a string you can write to a file.

Comment: Found the problem. I used a streamreader further above in my code. Now i've put `using` around it and now it works